# Select username with highest date time

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have an `sqlite database` with a `table Users` that looks as follow:

```
Username         |  InsertDateTime

User101             4/22/2013 11:44 
User102             3/22/2013 12:43
User103             4/22/2013 15:20
User104             1/21/2012 16:31
```

I want to `select` the `Username` with the `highest datetime`.
User103 in this case.

I tried some `queries` like:

```
Select Username from Users where InsertDateTime = MAX(datetime);
```

but this isn't a valid `sqlite query`.

Can somebody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT Username FROM Users ORDER BY InsertDateTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hopefully Sqlite will be smart enough not to actually perform a complete ordering :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Username
from Users
order by InsertDateTime desc
limit 1
```